# SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. windows 7

Tags: php, email, send

Well I'm using windows 7 and I am trying to send e-mail with mail() function in php.
I wrote and tried a lot but still can not send. This is my code:

```
 ini_set("SMTP","smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","25");


$to = 'asdf@gmail.com';
$subject = 'hi';
$msg = 'Test';
$headers ='Reply-To: shawn.danisa@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
        'From: postmaster@localhost' ."\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP /' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject,$msg,$headers);
```

and I get :

```
  SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. x42sm11770579eel.41 - gsmtp
```

I tried with port 587 but then I get :

```
    SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.      y51sm11859758eeu.0
```

Please help with port 465 my page even do not load. Again I am using windows 7.

Comment: You need to "log in" first, i.e. there are some scripts around the internet (much like yours above), that include a username and password.  It is to stop people abusing mail servers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a library like Swiftmailer that will handle this for you: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html